# Connecting Pyth.Network to C#

Tags: c#, solana

Hello I am looking for some help to implement JSON RPC in C# to be able to read data from Pyth.Network.

I know this is a general question. I've attempted some examples but I am not able to get all the necessary libraries to make something work.

Would anyone be able to offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you can take a look at the community package for Solana C# integration: https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet

After that, you'll need to add the structures from the program (data and instructions) in order to properly use Pyth in C#.  There are examples of other programs integrated in the C# library at https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/tree/master/src/Solnet.Programs

For Pyth specifically, you'll need to add all of the client types to a C# library.  They already have many client libraries you can use as inspiration: Rust, C++, and JS.  Here's the Rust one for reference: https://github.com/pyth-network/pyth-client-rs/blob/main/src/lib.rs

There's some work to do, but not too much!